# Django image rotation mobile

Tags: django, image, rotation, python-imaging-library

I have deployed a django site with django 1.9, and whenever the image is uploaded as a Portrait from mobile (both camera and gallery), it auto-rotates to a landscape image. Any ideas on how do I stop this?